# Convert NSDate to NSString with a small bug

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I used this snippet to convert a given date to a string.  But if the date happens to have a time of less than 5:00 then the result is a prior date.  For example, this date: "07-01-15  05:00:00 +0000" will work correctly.  But a "07-01-15  04:49:00 +0000" will have a prior date as the result.

Any suggestions?

```
+(NSString *)stringFromGivenDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM-dd-yy";
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"date: %@", dateString);
    return dateString;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSDateFormatter by default sets the time zone to your locale time zone.

But while converting date to string changes the time to GMT time.

So you have to set the time zone using

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]
```

or whatever timezone you want(like `@"GMT+5:30"`).

So your code will be like:

```
+(NSString *)stringFromGivenDate:(NSDate *)date
{
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM-dd-yy";
  dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]
  NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
  NSLog(@"date: %@", dateString);
return dateString;
}
```